# Convert XML-structured data into a Pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, xml, dataframe

I want to convert data structured as XML [here on this page](https://www.resultats-elections.interieur.gouv.fr/telechargements/PR2022/resultatsT1/011/077/077001.xml) into a more functional Pandas dataframe.

This is my code so far to get the XML data from the URL into my notebook. I tried to get the two first columns (Type and Annee) to start but it doesn't return anything.

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

with urlopen('https://www.resultats-elections.interieur.gouv.fr/telechargements/PR2022/resultatsT1/011/077/077001.xml') as f:
    tree = ET.parse(f)
    root = tree.getroot()
    
    for _id in root[0].findall('Election'):
        Type = _id.find('Type').text
        Annee = _id.find('Annee').text
        print(Type, Annee)
```

Answer (score 1):

a combination of the excellent [requests](https://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/) library and pandas should get the job done.

```
import pandas
import requests

url = r"https://www.resultats-elections.interieur.gouv.fr/telechargements/PR2022/resultatsT1/011/077/077001.xml"
with requests.get(url) as resp:
    df = pandas.read_xml(resp.text)

print(df.head())
```

Comment: When I manually import the XML data into Excel, I understand that a dataframe of 13 rows and 33 columns should be returned, but it's a step forward to the right answer

Comment: [**`read_xml`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/dev/reference/api/pandas.read_xml.html) can directly read URLs.

Comment: Does it work with https now as well? Previously had issue with SSL